# Nan value when calculate difference between two dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to calculate the difference between two dates but the result I get is `NaN`, this is my code:

```
 var date1 = $("#dateb").val();
 var date2 = $("#datea").val();
 var date_difference = parseInt((date1-date2)/(24*3600*1000));
 alert(date_difference);  // NaN
```

Notice in my datepicker I am using this format:

```
$('.datePicker').datepicker({
   format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
{);
```

Comment: You would need to convert the text to an actual Date() object first...

Comment: Moment.js is a good library for manipulating dates easily. https://momentjs.com/

Comment: first search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between 2 dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

first, convert into date

```
function parseDate(input) {
    // Transform date from text to date
    var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
    // new Date(year, month [, date [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
    return new Date(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2]); // months are 0-based
}
var date1 = parseDate($("#dateb").val());
var date2 = parseDate($("#datea").val());
var diff = date1 - date2 ; 
var date_difference=parseInt(diff /(24*3600*1000));
alert(date_difference);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you must convert the dates into `Date` objects before subtracting them:

```
var date1 = new Date($("#dateb").val());
var date2 = new Date($("#datea").val());
var date_difference = Math.ceil((date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Answer (score 0):

i didnt see how is the val of both inputs, expecting goes in this match MM-dd-yyy", this is an [aproximation](http://jsfiddle.net/yapu9a6m/16/) of would be:

```
var date1 = +new Date(2017,1,9).getTime();
var date2 = +new Date('09-10-2017').getTime();
var date_difference=(date1-date2)/(24*3600*1000);
console.log(date1, date2, new Date(date_difference));
```

Expect it help you

Comment: Thanks Steve And Alvaro Touzon the code dont work, my first code work in Format MM-dd-yyy but me i want this format yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: yo do like @Sanyami Vaidya, to split the value as you needed and JS need

Comment: Tnanks alvaro it work for me using the solution of Sanyami Vaidya thanks for you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet with a working example from [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript). Just run the snippet below to see how it returns a count of days for the difference  between the two dates:

```js
var date1 = new Date("7/13/2017");
var date2 = new Date("12/15/2017");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays);
```